# Unable to get the PublishAssetURL in azure media Service

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-storage, azure-media-services, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload the mp4 file from Controller into azure blob storage right after when i done uploading, i am creating asset from the same blob which i just uploaded every thing seems working fine but i don't know some how i am unable to get the publishAssetURL

`var manifestFile = asset.AssetFiles.Where(x => 
                 x.Name.EndsWith(".ism")).FirstOrDefault();`

This issue is on this line the `manifestFile` is coming null.

```
    public string CreateAssetFromExistingBlobs(CloudBlobContainer sourceBlobContainer, CloudStorageAccount _destinationStorageAccount, CloudMediaContext _context, AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider )
    {
        CloudBlobClient destBlobStorage = _destinationStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Create a new asset. 
        IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create("NewAsset_" + Guid.NewGuid(), AssetCreationOptions.None);

        IAccessPolicy writePolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("writePolicy",
            TimeSpan.FromHours(24), AccessPermissions.Write);

        ILocator destinationLocator =
            _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, writePolicy);

        // Get the asset container URI and Blob copy from mediaContainer to assetContainer. 
        CloudBlobContainer destAssetContainer =
            destBlobStorage.GetContainerReference((new Uri(destinationLocator.Path)).Segments[1]);

        if (destAssetContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            destAssetContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });
        }

        var blob = sourceBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault().LocalFileName);
        blob.FetchAttributes();

        var assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(blob.Name);
        CopyBlob(blob, destAssetContainer);
        assetFile.ContentFileSize = blob.Properties.Length;
        assetFile.Update();
        asset.Update();

        destinationLocator.Delete();
        writePolicy.Delete();

        // Set the primary asset file.
        // If, for example, we copied a set of Smooth Streaming files, 
        // set the .ism file to be the primary file. 
        // If we, for example, copied an .mp4, then the mp4 would be the primary file. 
        var ismAssetFile = asset.AssetFiles.ToList().
            Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".mp4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

        // The following code assigns the first .ism file as the primary file in the asset.
        // An asset should have one .ism file.  
        if (ismAssetFile != null)
        {
            ismAssetFile.IsPrimary = true;
            ismAssetFile.Update();
        }

        IAsset encodedAsset = EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set(asset, _context);

       return PublishAssetGetURLs(encodedAsset, _context);


    }

    private void CopyBlob(ICloudBlob sourceBlob, CloudBlobContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        var signature = sourceBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
        });

        var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlob.Name);

        if (destinationBlob.Exists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Destination blob '{0}' already exists. Skipping.", destinationBlob.Uri));
        }
        else
        {

            // Display the size of the source blob.
            Console.WriteLine(sourceBlob.Properties.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Copy blob '{0}' to '{1}'", sourceBlob.Uri, destinationBlob.Uri));
            destinationBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));

            while (true)
            {
                // The StartCopyFromBlob is an async operation, 
                // so we want to check if the copy operation is completed before proceeding. 
                // To do that, we call FetchAttributes on the blob and check the CopyStatus. 
                destinationBlob.FetchAttributes();
                if (destinationBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Pending)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //It's still not completed. So wait for some time.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            // Display the size of the destination blob.
            Console.WriteLine(destinationBlob.Properties.Length);

        }
    }

    private IAsset EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set(IAsset asset, CloudMediaContext _context)
    {
        // Declare a new job.
        IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("Media Encoder Standard Job");
        // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
        // processor to use for the specific task.
        IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Media Encoder Standard",_context);

        // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
        // In this case "Adaptive Streaming" preset is used.
        ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task",
            processor,
            "Adaptive Streaming",
            TaskOptions.None);

        // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
        task.InputAssets.Add(asset);
        // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job. 
        // This output is specified as AssetCreationOptions.None, which 
        // means the output asset is not encrypted. 
        task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output asset",
            AssetCreationOptions.None);

        job.StateChanged += new EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs>(JobStateChanged);
        job.Submit();
        job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None).Wait();

        return job.OutputMediaAssets[0];
    }


    public void JobStateChanged(object sender, JobStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Job state changed event:");
        //Console.WriteLine("  Previous state: " + e.PreviousState);
        //Console.WriteLine("  Current state: " + e.CurrentState);
        switch (e.CurrentState)
        {
            case JobState.Finished:
                //Console.WriteLine();
                //Console.WriteLine("Job is finished. Please wait while local tasks or downloads complete...");
                break;
            case JobState.Canceling:
            case JobState.Queued:
            case JobState.Scheduled:
            case JobState.Processing:
                //Console.WriteLine("Please wait...\n");
                break;
            case JobState.Canceled:
            case JobState.Error:

                // Cast sender as a job.
                IJob job = (IJob)sender;

                // Display or log error details as needed.
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    private IMediaProcessor GetLatestMediaProcessorByName(string mediaProcessorName, CloudMediaContext _context)
    {
        var processor = _context.MediaProcessors.Where(p => p.Name == mediaProcessorName).
        ToList().OrderBy(p => new Version(p.Version)).LastOrDefault();

        if (processor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unknown media processor", mediaProcessorName));

        return processor;
    }


    private string PublishAssetGetURLs(IAsset asset, CloudMediaContext _context)
    {



        // Create a 30-day readonly access policy. 
        // You cannot create a streaming locator using an AccessPolicy that includes write or delete permissions.
        IAccessPolicy policy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("Streaming policy",
            TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
            AccessPermissions.Read);

        // Create a locator to the streaming content on an origin. 
        ILocator originLocator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, asset,
            policy,
            DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));

        // Display some useful values based on the locator.
        //Console.WriteLine("Streaming asset base path on origin: ");
        //Console.WriteLine(originLocator.Path);
        //Console.WriteLine();

        // Get a reference to the streaming manifest file from the  
        // collection of files in the asset. 

        var manifestFile = asset.AssetFiles.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith(".ism")).FirstOrDefault();





        // Create a full URL to the manifest file. Use this for playback
        // in streaming media clients. 
        string urlForClientStreaming = originLocator.Path + manifestFile.Name + "/manifest";
       // Console.WriteLine("URL to manifest for client streaming using Smooth Streaming protocol: ");
       // Console.WriteLine(urlForClientStreaming);
       // Console.WriteLine("URL to manifest for client streaming using HLS protocol: ");
        return urlForClientStreaming + "(format=m3u8-aapl)";
       // Console.WriteLine("URL to manifest for client streaming using MPEG DASH protocol: ");
       // Console.WriteLine(urlForClientStreaming + "(format=mpd-time-csf)");
       // Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the Asset ID (for the Asset sent to PublishAssetGetURLs()), and the data center used?

Comment: @AnilMurching nb:cid:UUID:d2e2589d-01ab-47e2-88ab-8089d97ebaec
West Europe

Comment: @AnilMurching i am waiting on you to look into this

Answer (score 1):

Checked our logs - the reason you are not getting the streaming URL is that the encode Job failed. At the end of EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set(), you should confirm that the final Job status was Finished (i.e. successful). Looking at the encoder logs, it appears that the input file was corrupt.

Comment: Yes, i found out that the uploading file was corrupted 
Thanks